# How to pass path as parameter to a custom made context menu option?

Tags: c#, windows, contextmenu

I have created a custom context menu option. This option would remove the file from where it is called. The custom context menu was successfully added and also it calls my remove application. But the problem is i dont know how to pass the path to remove.exe of the file from where it is called.

Here is my custom context menu code

```
RegistryKey _key = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey("*\\Shell", true);
RegistryKey newkey = _key.CreateSubKey("Remove");
newkey.SetValue("AppliesTo", "under:T:");

RegistryKey subNewkey = newkey.CreateSubKey("Command");
subNewkey.SetValue("", "C:\\remove.exe");
subNewkey.Close();

newkey.Close();
_key.Close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
subNewkey.SetValue("", "C:\\remove.exe");
```

to this:

```
subNewkey.SetValue("", "C:\\remove.exe %1");
```

The OS sends the filename of the clicked on file as %1.

Comment: Yeah, got it. The argv[1] of remove.exe gives the full path of the file which calls it. Thanks